# PHPSESSID cookie ill defined

Tags: php

I use EasyPHP-Devserver version 17.0 to test a website of my own. When accessing this website on localhost, my navigator (Firefox 88.0.1) issues a console message telling that the PHPSESSID cookie has a SameSite attrbiute which is either 'None' or invalid, and doesn't have the 'secure' attribute.

I have modified the php.ini file by adding

```
session.cookie_samesite = Strict
session.cookie_secure = 1
```

*(I also tried varied combinations using "Strict" instead of Strict, session.cookie_SameSite, etc.)*
 Then I restart all the EasyPHP servers, and reload the URL. However, I still get the firefox message.
What did I miss ?

Thanks in advance for any explanation and/or solution.

*(For sure, I didn't catch everything about cookies and PHP sessions)*.

Comment: https://hacks.mozilla.org/2020/08/changes-to-samesite-cookie-behavior/

Comment: Thanks, this works. But my goal was more to have this "cookie.sameSite" set to "Lax" by EasyPHP, rather than only making it a default setting specifically for Firefox (EasyPHP support site bounces me back to stackoverflow...).